# AWS S3 Multipart upload restarting when reaching 12MB of loaded data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm struggling to upload files using AWS S3 Multipart inside my angular application. Upload begins but restarts after reaching 12 MB of loaded data.

**logs**:

```
Object {loaded: 12582912, total: 91015730, part: 3, key: "IMG_2973.MOV"}
postVideo.js:46 14% done
postVideo.js:47 Object {loaded: 12582912, total: 91015730, part: 4, key: "IMG_2973.MOV"}
postVideo.js:46 8% done
postVideo.js:47 Object {loaded: 7684096, total: 91015730, part: 2, key: "IMG_2973.MOV"}
postVideo.js:46 7% done
postVideo.js:47 Object {loaded: 6078464, total: 91015730, part: 4, key: "IMG_2973.MOV"}
postVideo.js:46 4% done
postVideo.js:47 Object {loaded: 3850240, total: 91015730, part: 3, key: "IMG_2973.MOV"}
postVideo.js:46 1% done
Object {loaded: 589824, total: 91015730, part: 1, key: "IMG_2973.MOV"}
postVideo.js:46 1% done
postVideo.js:47 Object {loaded: 622592, total: 91015730, part: 4, key: "IMG_2973.MOV"}
postVideo.js:46 1% done
postVideo.js:47 Object {loaded: 655360, total: 91015730, part: 3, key: "IMG_2973.MOV"}
postVideo.js:46 1% done
```

The application retries a few times but then gets timeout.

I'm pretty much lost here and any thoughts will be helpful.

---

**CORS**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-id-2</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

**code**:

```
$scope.upload = function() {
    // Configure The S3 Object 
    $scope.creds = $publisherServices.getAwsCreds();
    AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: $scope.creds.access_key, secretAccessKey: $scope.creds.secret_key });
    //AWS.config.region = 'sa-east-1';
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01', params: {Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket}});

    if($scope.file) {
      var params = { Key: $scope.file.name, ContentType: $scope.file.type, Body: $scope.file};
      bucket.upload(params).
        on('httpUploadProgress', function(progress) {
          console.log(Math.round(progress.loaded / progress.total * 100) + '% done');
          console.log(progress);
        }).send(function(err, data) { console.log(err, data) });
    } else {
      // No File Selected
      alert('No File Selected');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you check your angular apps upload limit?

Comment: Where is this configuration set?

Comment: Sorry, I overlook the issue.  When calling put_object(), there should be no restriction from API itself.  This looks like behavior of corporate firewall/proxy/loadbalancer that limit file upload.  This looks like a network issues.

Comment: @mootmoot i'm being able to upload files directly from the S3 dashboard. So i dont think the problem is my network.

Comment: IMHO, it is a good idea to use multipart upload.  
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html 

The client of S3 dashboard is a java servlet , IMHO, make use of multipart upload.

Comment: @mootmoot It is currently using multipart upload as you can see in the logs. I follow this documentation (https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/javascript/post/Tx3EQZP53BODXWF/Announcing-the-Amazon-S3-Managed-Uploader-in-the-AWS-SDK-for-JavaScript) to design my code.

Comment: worth a check your   $scope.maxFileSizeMb  properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help given in the [topic opened in aws-sdk-js github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/949) I was able to fix the issue. The fact is that there is a 2 minute timeout  pre configured for the parts.

To disable it just set the httpOptions timeout:

```
var bucket = new AWS.S3({
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01', 
  httpOptions: {timeout: 0}, 
  params: {Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket}
});
```